# Base for Laptop/Projector

Tags: projector

Kind of odd question, I need a base for my laptop that has to allow me to ajust its 4 legs independently. 
For example i want the project to lean forward and at the same it to the right.
I will have to be able to adjust the height of each leg until i reach my ideal spot.

Do you happen to know of any base like this? ( can be a laptop base ) as long as its steady.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not asking for a computer hardware recommendation.